# Существует пример реализации ViewPager внутри DialogFragmen?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, dialogfragment

Есть примеры кода реализации ViewPager внутри какого либо DialogFragment?
Находил некоторые примеры, но каждый раз возникали разные ошибки которые не позволяли понять в чем все таки проблема, по сему прошу полный пример от и до содержащий по возможности xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Tab_1.class

```
public class Tab_1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
  }
}
```

### Tab_2.class

```
public class Tab_2 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);
  }
}
```

### Tab_3.class

```
public class Tab_3 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_3, container, false);
  }
}
```

### tab_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#c8ff0004"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="Tab 1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### tab_2.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#c80044ff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Tab 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### tab_3.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#c85eff00"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Tab 3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### MainActivity.class

*Кнопка вызова кастомного диалога.*

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        new FragmentsPopup().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context="com.app.shwarz.viewpager_fragments_dialog_ver10.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Dialog"
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### PageAdapter.class

```
    public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments){
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

### FragmentsPopup.class

*Ну и сам класс диалога, ради чего всё это.*

```
    public class FragmentsPopup extends DialogFragment {
    PageAdapter pageAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_activity, container);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getFragments());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //уберем a_bar
        return view;
    }

    private List getFragments(){
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new Tab_1());
        list.add(new Tab_2());
        list.add(new Tab_3());
        return list;
    }
}
```

### dialog_activity.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Все превосходно работает!