# Как сделать в DialogFragment ViewPager

Tags: android, dialogfragment, android-viewpager

Собственно проблема следующая, хочу вставить в диалоговое окно ViewPager.
Делаю это следующим образом, разметка самого диалога:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/scheduler_datetime"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Код самого диалога:

```
public class SchedulerAddEditDialog extends DialogFragment {
    ViewPager mDateTimePicker;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_scheduler_addedit, null);
         mDateTimePicker = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduler_datetime);
         PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
         mDateTimePicker.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
         builder.setView(view);
         builder.setTitle(R.string.scheduler);
         builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             }
         });

         AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

         return dialog;

     }

    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "position is " + position);
        if (position == 0){
            return new DatePickerFragment();
        } else if (position == 1){
            return new TimePickerFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
}
```

Сами фрагменты просто болванки

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends Fragment {

DatePicker mDatePicker;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_datepicker, container, false);
    mDatePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduler_datepicker);
    return view;
}
}
```

И его разметка

```
<DatePicker
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scheduler_datepicker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Второй фрагмент брат близнец

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_timepicker, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

и разметка

```
<TimePicker
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scheduler_timepicker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

При вызове диалога возникает такая вот ошибка

> --------- beginning of crash
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: myenv.roadmap4, PID: 3010
>                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0090 (myenv.roadmap4:id/scheduler_datetime) for fragment DatePickerFragment{29fcac0a #2 id=0x7f0e0090}
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)

Стоит закомментерировать это дело так тут же все становится хорошо...
PS
В строчке

```
       PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

пытался ставить

```
       PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

та же самая ошибка :(

Comment: Попробуйте getChildFragmentManager() в ViewPager передавать

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508153/191270.  Старый код, но думаю еще актуальный

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожалению нет, получаю ошибку  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте местами строки :

```
 mDateTimePicker.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
 PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

Должно быть так:

```
 PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
 mDateTimePicker.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

Comment: У меня именно так как у Вас написано строки стоят, это я когда копировал ошибся. Сорри